# AJAX errors: 403 forbidden

Tags: ajax, http

I created an ajax call and I tried it calling many websites but it doesn't work, even if it's apparently correct:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container">Content here</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var url = "http://www.nasa.gov/";

        jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
                jQuery("#Container").empty().html(data);
           },
           error: function(data) {
               alert("error");
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Depending on the page I can get one of the following errors:

"NetworkError: 501 Not Implemented - http://www.nasa.gov/"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.cerealsevent.co.uk/"

"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - ... etc

Other times there are no error, but the data returned is empty.

What's the problem?

Comment: Why use post and not get ?

Answer (score 1):

For security issues cross domain ajax call are not allowed in standard way (follow this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). If you really want to send a remote Ajax call to the other domain you should do in a different way. take a look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).